# Join 3 tables with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, lambda

I basically want the following sql query as a lambda expression:

```
SELECT studentname, coursename, grade
FROM student S, course C, grade G
WHERE S.id = G.studentid AND C.coursecode = G.coursecode AND G.grade<='B';
```

I am having trouble as I have to join 3 tables together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that looks something like this as a query expression:

```
var q = from grade in db.Grades
        where grade.grade <= 'B'
        join student in db.Students on grade.studentid equals student.studentid
        join course in db.Courses on grade.coursecode equals course.coursecode
        select new { student.studentname, course.coursename, grade.grade };
```

(I'd normally use a variable name of `query` instead of `q` - I've just used `q` for formatting purposes here.)

You *could* translate this into explicit `Join` calls with lambda expressions, but I'd strongly advise you to use query expressions for complex queries like this.

Note that I've changed the order of the query to allow the "where" clause to be expressed as simply and efficiently as possible. In all likelihood a SQL query planner would optimize it anyway, but for something like LINQ to Objects this would help.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: True, but I've taken some liberties anyway like assuming a context of `db`... and IIRC, some LINQ designers will pluralize table names anyway. If the OP can't work out what's going on and remove an "s" if necessary, they've got bigger problems...